# Example when f(x) does not vanish at infinity

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a homework question that asks to give an example of a random variable X with a probability density f(x) such that the limit as f(x) goes to positive infinity does not exist. So, we want to find an example when f(x) does not vanish at infinity.

I am completely stuck on this one, I have no idea where to begin. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a countable sum of characteristic functions of intervals, for example 
$$f(x):=\frac 1C\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\chi_{(2k,2k+2^{-k+1})}(x),$$
where $C$ is a normalizing constant.

Consider $x_n:=2n+2^{-n}$; then $f(x_n)=2n/C$. On the other hand, with $y_n:=2n+1$, $f(y_n)=0$, hence $f$ has no limit as $x$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on this? I don't think we've covered anything with characteristic functions of intervals in class

Comment: Let $x$ be a real number. If $x$ belong to an interval of the form $(k,k+2^{-k})$ for some integer $k$ (uniquely determined), then $f(x)=k$. If $x$ isn't in such an interval, then $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I still don't really understand how to show that the function above will not exist as x goes to infinity

Comment: I changed a little bit the function in order to show that the limit does exist (there are no major changes, I wanted to make it more readable).